# ASP.NET redirect unauthorised user to default/login page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a simpe website with different levels of access. I have used the asp.net configuration security feature to create users and roles. Login works, logout works, access to the right pages is granted to people with the right role.

However, i am struggling to find a way to redirect people who are not in the right role or are not logged in when they try to access restricted content.

How can I redirect instead of just getting the 404 error page?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default forms authentication redirects the user to a page with the name `login.aspx` when he/she tries to access a restricted resource to whom he/she currently has no permission. So if you don't have the `login.aspx` the resource not found error(`HTTP 404`) will be thrown. `To overcome this create the login.aspx` page or tell asp.net to use another page(yourloginpage.aspx) as the login page. To do the latter you should define it in the `<forms>` tag in your web.config as suggested by `sathishkumar indian`

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="yourloginPage.aspx" />
 </authentication>
```

Answer (score 1):

In web.config you should set like this,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
    defaultUrl="index.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

All the unauthorized persons will redirect to  member_login.aspx page.