# Redirect different user to another URL

Tags: asp.net, .net

I created different roles (such as Admin, Active user, User, ...) in my web system. The user get Authenticated by built in ASP: log in and I've different folder for different user roles.
Any user group have a folder and web config page to allow or denied to access the folder's pages.

**Now my question is:**
 
**How to redirect a user from a page that not have a permission to see it, to another page like access denied.aspx page?**

for more info:
I want when a "user" click on the manager's page, it redirect to access denied.aspx page.

Note: 
 
If exit a way to don't show manager's page for user group, please say that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in masterpage

```
if (!(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin")))
{
  Response.Redirect("UnAuthenticatedUser.aspx");
}
```

Comment: This link will also help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046043/asp-net-redirect-unauthorised-user-to-default-login-page

Answer (score 0):

in manager's pageload:

```
if (!User.IsInRole("managers")) {
    Response.redirect("denied.aspx")
}
```

or something like that?